# var Notify = require('notifyjs'); renders instant ReferenceError

Tags: node.js, notifyjs

I am attempting to implement Notifications for my node.js app with Notify.js:
https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js

When I do:

```
var Notify = require('notifyjs');
```

It instantly return this error when starting the app:

```
...\notify.js:18}(window, function (w, d) {
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Unsure of how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This package is only for web browsers or node-webkit. [This](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah. Thank you, Ben. I've tried that module and it has some issues on my raspberry pi that's running the app. I guess I'll use the standard html5 notification.